# Update for phone support sits forever

Tags: macos, iphone

When I connect my iPhone SE to my 2014 MacBook Pro, I get a message that it needs to install an update to support that phone.

[image]

When I select 'Install' I get download dialog that sits forever at 0%

[image]

My MacBook Pro is at Mac OS 11.7.5 (20G1225)

My iPhone SE is at iOS 16.1.2

My Internet connection works just fine.

Comment: Try updating your mac (to the latest version of Ventura or max version possible at least) from System Prefs and not from this dialog, then, try again.

Comment: My mac is at latest possible OS version. Mac Book Pro 2014 is not supported by newer OS versions. When I upgraded my phone's iOS, the download did succeed, though.